# Custom List<Of Something>

Tags: c#, list

So I'm trying to create something that will store an invoice number along with the user; so I made a class and extended the base class for it. I find it really hard to explain for some reason so I'll just put the code in first:

Base Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
namespace AMS 
{
    public class AMSclient
    {
        private string clientFirstName;     //Client first name
        private string clientLastName;      //Client last name
        private string phoneNumber;         //Client phone number.
        private string streetAddress;       //Client street address.
        private string state;               //Client state.
        private string zip;                 //Client zip.
        private string paymentMethod;       //Client payment method (Credit card, BTC, cash)
        private DateTime dateCreated;       //Date + time client is created.
        private string email;               //Client email.
        private int lockedUser;             //If you need a password to view client.
        private string userPassword;        //empty is default if lockedUser != 1
        private string groupName;           //If client is in group.
        private string clientImage;         //Client Image.
        private long clientID;              //Clients ID number.
        #region Getters/Setters and all that good shit.
        public string ClientFirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return clientFirstName;
            }

            set
            {
                clientFirstName = value;
            }
        }

        public string ClientLastName
        {
            get
            {
                return clientLastName;
            }

            set
            {
                clientLastName = value;
            }
        }

        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return phoneNumber;
            }

            set
            {
                phoneNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public string StreetAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return streetAddress;
            }

            set
            {
                streetAddress = value;
            }
        }

        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }

            set
            {
                state = value;
            }
        }

        public string Zip
        {
            get
            {
                return zip;
            }

            set
            {
                zip = value;
            }
        }

        public string PaymentMethod
        {
            get
            {
                return paymentMethod;
            }

            set
            {
                paymentMethod = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return dateCreated;
            }

            set
            {
                dateCreated = value;
            }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return email;
            }

            set
            {
                email = value;
            }
        }

        public int LockedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return lockedUser;
            }

            set
            {
                lockedUser = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserPassword
        {
            get
            {
                return userPassword;
            }

            set
            {
                userPassword = value;
            }
        }

        public string GroupName
        {
            get
            {
                return groupName;
            }

            set
            {
                groupName = value;
            }
        }
        public string imageClient
        {
            get
            {
                return clientImage;
            }

            set
            {
                clientImage = value;
            }

        }

         public long clientsID
        {
            get
            {
                return clientID;
            }

            set
            {
                clientID = value;
            }
        }



        #endregion

        //Contruct that shit, and fuck you I like the 'this'.
        public AMSclient(string first, string last, string number, string address,
        string state, string zip, string method, DateTime date, string email, int locked, string userPass, string group, string i)
        {
            this.clientFirstName = first;
            this.clientLastName = last;
            this.phoneNumber = number;
            this.streetAddress = address;
            this.state = state;
            this.zip = zip;
            this.paymentMethod = method;
            this.dateCreated = date;
            this.email = email;
            this.lockedUser = locked;
            this.userPassword = userPass;
            this.groupName = group;
            this.clientImage = i;

            //ClientID set and save via Settings.
            this.clientID = AMS.Properties.Settings.Default.clientIDValue;
            this.clientID += 1;
            AMS.Properties.Settings.Default.clientIDValue += 1;
            AMS.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();



        }
    }
}
```

Extension Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AMS
{

    public class AMSInvoiceList : AMSclient
    {
        private AMSclient c;
        private string btcInvoiceNum;

        public AMSInvoiceList(AMSclient client, string invoicenum) : base(client.ClientFirstName, client.ClientLastName,client.PhoneNumber,
            client.StreetAddress, client.State, client.Zip, client.PaymentMethod, client.DateCreated, client.Email, client.LockedUser, client.UserPassword, client.GroupName, client.imageClient)
        {
            this.c = client;
            this.btcInvoiceNum = invoicenum;
        }

    }
}
```

Invoice Class:

```
//Creates an invoice number for the BTC Transaction.
        //1000 - "1" before the "0"s represent a BTC type invoice.
        public string createInvoiceNumber(long clientid)
        {
             AMS.Properties.Settings.Default.btcInvoiceValue += 1;
             return clientid + "-" + "1000" + AMS.Properties.Settings.Default.btcInvoiceValue;

        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that I can store invoices of this payment method in a "custom" type list; I list that would contain everything from the base class + the invoice number that has been created, I hope that makes sense.
So then if I do this (just say):

```
 AMSInvoiceList a = new AMSInvoiceList(client, "edsudiopjsipodjips");
        List<AMSInvoiceList> ax = new List<AMSInvoiceList>();
```

That when I make an invoice I can just call 
 `AMSInvoiceList a = new AMSInvoiceList(client, "edsudiopjsipodjips");` and then add it to a global list ("ax" for example); so that when I want I can just call `ax[0]` all the information from the base class (all client information) will be displayed along with the invoice number. I hope this makes sense guys, I just can't make heads or tails here!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a `Dictionary<string, AMSClient>` ?

Comment: First thing to do: learn about automatically-implemented properties. They will cut your code size down *massively*.

Comment: I've never really used Dictionary only really stuck to List<T> can you give me an example of how that would go + some information in an answer :)?

Comment: Wish that SO's code formatter could toggle these regions.

Comment: You mean getters and setters like `Type Property {get; set;}` ? If you're referring to that I really like to actually write out my getters and setters, call me old fashion ;).

Comment: Why are you using composition and inheritance?  Basically why does `AMSInvoiceList` have to inherit from `AMSclient` when it contains one?

Comment: That was just my thought process on how to do such a thing, which is why I asked for help haha. I figure I would need to extend it, but I see what you mean now!

Comment: Well if I don't inherit from it, it's asking me for arguments on "client"...?

Comment: Can you expand on the meaning of your final paragraph? How does calling `ax[0]` make all the information "be displayed"? What problem are you running into when you try to do this?

Comment: It was just an example; meaning just say I wanna store something in that list it would be thew first index, so I could display everything in the AMSClient class (Zip, state, ect) along with the invoice number that is being set in the other class. I wanna be able to pull both those things from one entry in a list, ya know?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, AMSClient>` I'm so stupid, please put that as an answer so I can mark it :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary<String, AMSClient>` is the answer (from [ananthonline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802203/ananthonline)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619545/custom-listof-something/34635379#comment56984560_34619545)) that solved my problem, thank you guys!